# Flutter Pusher Private Channel Notification Problem

Tags: laravel, flutter, notifications, pusher

I use `pusher-channels-flutter` package in my flutter app, the back-end is Laravel.
when I connect to Pusher it gives me this error.

```
[  +65 ms] I/PusherChannelsFlutter(20214): Start com.pusher.client.Pusher@4083fc0
[ +102 ms] I/flutter (20214): LOG: Connection: CONNECTING
[+1566 ms] I/flutter (20214): LOG: Connection: CONNECTED
[+1566 ms] I/flutter (20214): LOG: onSubscriptionError: Unable to parse response from Authorizer: null Exception: com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: Unable to parse
response from Authorizer: null
```

this is pusher init function.

```
void onConnect() async {
    if (!_channelFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      await pusher.init(
        apiKey: _apiKey,
        cluster: _cluster,
        onConnectionStateChange: onConnectionStateChange,
        onError: onError,
        onSubscriptionSucceeded: onSubscriptionSucceeded,
        onEvent: onEvent,
        onSubscriptionError: onSubscriptionError,
        onDecryptionFailure: onDecryptionFailure,
        onMemberAdded: onMemberAdded,
        onMemberRemoved: onMemberRemoved,
        //authEndpoint: "https://my-website.com/broadcasting/auth",
        onAuthorizer: onAuthorizer,
      );
      await pusher.subscribe(channelName: _channelName.text);
      await pusher.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      print("$e");
      log("ERROR: $e");
    }
  }
```

and this is `onAuthorizer` function

```
 dynamic onAuthorizer(
      String channelName, String socketId, dynamic options) async {
    var authUrl = "https://my-website.com/broadcasting/auth";
    var result = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(authUrl),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
      },
      body: 'socket_id=' + socketId + '&channel_name=' + channelName,
    );
    return jsonDecode(result.body);
  }
```

It seems request to `authUrl = "https://my-website.com/broadcasting/auth"` retun null, I tried `Content-Type` as `json` but return same result.

```
  headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
      }
```

if anyone integrated pusher with flutter please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging for hours, the issue was that the body should be sent as an object

The authentication request goes to the following function:

```
// Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster.php

/**
 * Authenticate the incoming request for a given channel.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException
 */
public function auth($request)
{
    $channelName = $this->normalizeChannelName($request->channel_name);

    if (
        empty($request->channel_name) ||
        ($this->isGuardedChannel($request->channel_name) &&
            !$this->retrieveUser($request, $channelName))
    ) {
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException;
    }

    return parent::verifyUserCanAccessChannel(
        $request,
        $channelName
    );
}
```

If you tried to Log::info($request) you will find that the request from your code is empty array, so to solve this issue you can just make the body as object

```
dynamic onAuthorizer(String channelName, String socketId, dynamic options) async {
    var authUrl = authEndpoint;
    try {
      var result = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(authUrl),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ${userToken}',
        },
        body: {'socket_id': socketId, 'channel_name': channelName},
      );
      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(result.body);
      print("Authorization response: $jsonResponse");
      return jsonResponse;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error during authorization: $e");
      throw e;
    }
  }
```